# Can´t download azure blob using proxies from python

Tags: python, proxy, azure-blob-storage

I´m trying to download a azure blob from a server which uses proxy. Right now, my code works perfectly in my local (without using proxy as it is not needed) but when I try to run it from a server where I need to use the proxy, it doesn´t work even though I followed the azure documentation. I get the following error:

`azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Authentication failed: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa5b831f760>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

This is the code:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient 
credential = ClientSecretCredential(self.tenant_id, self.client_id, self.client_secret)
proxy = {"http": proxy_value, "https": proxy_value}
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(
    account_url=storage_account_url, credential=credential, proxies=proxy, connection_verify=False
)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(
    container_name, blob_name, snapshot=None
)
blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
```

I´m 100% sure that all the values are correct as I have done other different tests that work.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I tried in my environment and got error,

> (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',  NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection
> object at 0x04755510>: Failed to establish a new connection:   [Errno11001] getaddrinfo failed',)))

The error occurs due to your proxy password may contains an **`@ symbol`**, which is causing your URL parsing to get confused. You need to **`URL encode`** your password (that is, run it through **`urllib.quote)`** before passing it or it gets pretty confusing.

You can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/azure-sdk-configure-proxy?tabs=bash) to set variable in the azure cli. I tried with **`urllib.parse`** with below python code I downloaded and read the content of file with proxy successfully.

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import json
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote


username = quote('type in username')  
password = quote(' type in password')  
proxy = 'type in proxy name or ip'  
proxy_port = '8080'

proxy_https = 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + proxy + ':' + proxy_port

proxies={ 'https': proxy_https}
tenant_id="<tenant id>"
client_id="<client id>"
client_secret="<client secret>"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id,client_id,client_secret)
storage_url="https://venkat12.blob.core.windows.net"

container_name="test"
blob_name="file.json"
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_url,proxy=proxies,credential=credential,connection_verify=True)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(
    container_name,blob_name, snapshot=None
)
blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob().readall()
raw=json.loads(blob_data)
print(raw)
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Can't get Proxy to work with https and http works only with auth, not like the Docu descripes · Issue #3990 · psf/requests (github.com)](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3990) by eisbaer9.

Comment: Hi @MiguelAnguloJiménez I tried with same format as `https://proxy:port` in my environment [Snapshot](https://i.imgur.com/ab3Ym5e.png),it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much, I managed to solve it. I had already checked the documentation that you have sent but I had made a mistake before. Adding the proxy as a parameter when the blob client is instanced (BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_url,proxy=proxies,credential=credential,connection_verify=True)), doesn´t work but adding it as env variable, it does. And here it s my error, I had set the env variable like this: os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://proxy:port" but in my case, it had to be using the 's' os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"]. Adding that, it works.